# What is the difference between glBindImageTexture() and glBindTexture()?

Tags: opengl, texture2d, glteximage2d

What is the difference between glBindImageTexture and glBindTexture? And also what is the difference between the following declarations in a shader:

```
layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D img_input;
```

and

```
uniform sampler2D img_input;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ```
> layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D img_input;
> ```

That declares a [sampler](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29), which gets its data from a texture object. The binding of 0 (you can set that in the shader in GLSL 4.20) says that the 2D texture bound to texture image unit 0 (via `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);`) is the texture that will be used for this sampler.

Samplers use the *entire* texture, including all mipmap levels and array layers. Most texture sampling functions use normalized texture coordinates ([0, 1] map to the size of the texture). Most texture sampling functions also respect [filtering properties and other sampling parameters](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Sampling_parameters).

> ```
> layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D img_input;
> ```

This declares an image, which represents a *single image* from a texture. Textures can [have multiple images](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory): mipmap levels, [array layers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), etc. When you use `glBindImageTexture`, you are binding a single image from a texture.

Images and samplers are completely separate. They have their own set of binding indices; it's perfectly valid to bind a texture to `GL_TEXTURE0` and an image from a different texture to image binding 0. Using texture functions for the associated sampler will read from what is bound to `GL_TEXTURE0`, while image functions on the associated image variable will read from the image bound to image binding 0.

Image access ignores all sampling parameters. [Image accessing functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Image_operations) always use integer texel coordinates.

Samplers can only read data from textures; image variables can read and/or write data, as well as perform atomic operations on them. Of course, writing data from shaders requires special care, specifically when [someone goes to read that data](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access).